# Javascript canvas memory issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize an image in multiple steps to increase quality of the final image. This works fine in Opera browser, but i think there is a memory issue in Firefox. After resizing a few images, the following error occours: Error: Image corrupt or truncated: blob:[XY]. So my question: do you see a memory issue in the following code?

```
loadImage.halfSize = function (i) {
        var c = document.createElement("canvas");
        c.width = i.width / 2;
        c.height = i.height / 2;
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(i, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        return c;
    };

    loadImage.renderImageToCanvas = function (
        canvas,
        img,
        sourceX,
        sourceY,
        sourceWidth,
        sourceHeight,
        destX,
        destY,
        destWidth,
        destHeight
    ) {
            canvas.width = sourceWidth;
            canvas.height = sourceHeight;
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(
                img,
                sourceX,
                sourceY,
                sourceWidth,
                sourceHeight);

            if(sourceWidth <= destWidth && sourceHeight <= destHeight) {
                return canvas;
            }

            while (canvas.width > destWidth * 2) {
                canvas = loadImage.halfSize (canvas);
            }

            var canvasRes = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvasRes.width = destWidth;
            canvasRes.height = destHeight;
            var canvasResCtx = canvasRes.getContext("2d");
            canvasResCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvasRes.width, canvasRes.height);

            return canvasRes;
    };
```

I can't see a leak, because i'm using local variables everywhere, so memory of the created canvas-elements should be freed after each call to halfSize()?

Thanks for your help!
Ben

Comment: Hi Ben. To directly answer your question, no I can't see anything obviously wrong here. I've got it working on Firefox 30.0 (OSX) here: http://jsfiddle.net/mc38k/1/.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hmm, interesting, your standalone example seems to work in my Firefox. I think i need to analyse why it doesn't work in combination with my other code.